# bootstrap 2.3.2 popover html content issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to populate a `popover` dynamically through

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("[data-bind='popover']").popover({
 trigger: 'hover',
 html: true,
 content: function(){ 
  return "<img src="+$(this).data('content')+" />";
 };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="myreference.html" data-bind="popover" data-content="mylinktoimage">Brick</a>
```

the problem is that if I set `width` and `height` inside the `img` `tag` inside `js`, the `popover` shows up. If I don't set them, first of all the anchor `<a>` the `pointer cursor` "vibrate" and the `popover` is not shown.

What problem can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the above code actually works? Couldnt' even get the popover to work, eg

```
..
return "<img src="+$(this).data('content')+" />;
 });
```

?? Think that is your issue.

```
<a href="myreference.html" data-bind="popover" data-content="flower.jpg">Brick</a>
```

**update**, works with external online image as well

```
<a href="myreference.html" data-bind="popover" data-content="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/451px-Flower_poster_2.jpg">Brick</a>
```

and

```
$("[data-bind='popover']").popover({
   trigger: 'hover',
   html: true,
   content: function(){ 
      return '<img src="'+$(this).data('content')+'">';
   }
});
```

produces :

[image]

```
$("[data-bind='popover']").popover({
   trigger: 'hover',
   html: true,
   content: function(){ 
      return '<img src="'+$(this).data('content')+'" width="50">';
   }
});
```

produces

[image]

With no "vibrations" etc.

Comment: I know, I tried in an external file and it does not work, my html is a bit longer than the one I wrote in question, but the concept is the same

Comment: The problems seems to be with the `a` .. I don't know what to do, If i `mouseover` the anchor, the `pointer` and the `normal` cursor, alternate themselves.

Comment: @steo, and it does not work **even** if you make the <img> markup correct, as above? It sounds like you have an issue regarding the "I'm trying to populate a popover dynamically through" as you updated the question with. Have done a lot of bootstrapping, it cannot be bootstrap or the popover itself that is causing that error. Do you have any hover-effects in CSS? Or by javascript event?

Answer (score 1):

seems like a missing quote before semicolon:

`return "<img src="+$(this).data('content')+" />";`

Working Fiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/tEWLw/2/

**Update:** another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8DP4T/1/). I'm nost sure what else is wrong here :)

Comment: Yes! +1- Now it also shows the image, if you target one in data-content :) Dont know with scaling.